# Asymptotic regression function not correlating with raw data

Tags: r, regression, data-science, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to model raw data by an asymptotic function with the equation $$f(x) = a + (b-a)(1-\exp(-c x))$$ using R. To do so I used the following code:

```
rawData <- import("path/StackTestData.tsv")

# executing regression
X <- rawData$x
Y <- rawData$y
model <- drm(Y ~ X, fct = DRC.asymReg())

# creating the regression function
f_0_ <- model$coefficients[1] #value for y if x=0
steepness <- model$coefficients[2]
plateau <- model$coefficients[3] 
eq <- function(x){f_0_+(plateau-f_0_)*(1-exp(-steepness*x))}

# plotting the regression function together with the raw data
ggplot(rawData,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_line(col="red") +
  stat_function(fun=eq,col="blue") +
  ylim(10,12.5)
```

In some cases, I got a proper regression function. However, with the attached [data](http://sendanywhe.re/PW99ESG6) I don't get one. The regression function is not showing any correlation with the raw data whatsoever, as shown in the figure below. Can you perhaps offer a better solution for performing the asymptotic regression or do you know where the error lies?

[image]

Best Max

*R4.1.2 was used using R Studio 1.4.1106. For ggplot the package ggpubr, for DRC.asymReg() the packages aomisc and drc were load.*

Comment: I guess the question is more about the equation and not about coding? If so, the question should go to [CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: could you attach your data into the question? it is currently in a private google drive directory.

Comment: I think that I understood the equation but got anything wrong with my code or misunderstood what DRC.asymreg() does. However, I'll post it to CV as well. Have never heard of that forum so thank you for the advice.

Comment: @OttoKässi I just updated the link when you click on data

Comment: As I write above, your link points to a private google drive. Please attach your data using ?dput()

Comment: At least when I click on the link it is not pointing to google drive anymore. This should be the link: http://sendanywhe.re/PW99ESG6